# How to apply eslint rules on all parent folders

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, eslint, eslintrc

I am using AWS lambda dependencies layer which is a child folder that includes (node_modules and .eslintrc.json).

Project structure:

```
.
├── dependencies
|   └── nodejs
|       ├── utils
|       ├── services
|       ├── node_modules
|       ├── package.json
|       └── .eslintrc.json  
└── src
    └── signup
    |   ├── signup.js
    |   └── midllewares
    |       └── signup-validation.js
    └── login
        ├── login.js
        └── midllewares
            └── login-validation.js
```

My problem is that eslint rules don't work on javascript inside `src` directory, it only works inside `nodejs` directory.

How to apply the rules on all `.eslintrc.json`'s parent folders.

The solution I tried is to do `npm install` in the project root and move `.eslintrc.json` there, but it's an ugly solution to have `package.json` twice

- .eslintrc.json content

```json
{
  "env": {
    "commonjs": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
  "overrides": [],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
    "quotes": ["error", "single", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }],
    "no-unused-vars": ["error"],
    "no-var": ["error"],
    "prefer-const": ["warn"],
    "curly": ["error", "all"],
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 140 }],
    "camelcase": ["error", { "properties": "always" }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Afaik, eslint __only__ works on the current folder and its children.

Comment: it was working on all parent folders by default, and to make it work in the current folder only you should add `root: true` in `.eslintrc.json`

Comment: Can you install eslint globally and run it starting from the root path?

Comment: Yes, I can but it will be applied to all my projects including the legacy?